# IIF statements getting values from 2 different datasets Visual Studio 2012 (SSRS)

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have 2 Datasets containing different data that I want to link together. The 2 expressions below give me the correct values on their own but I have not been successful in combining them.

Expression 1:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Staff.Value = "Trainee",1,0), "Dataset1")
```

Expression 2:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "Pass" OR Fields!Grade.Value = "Achieved", 1, 0), "Dataset2")
```

I am trying to get the number of trainees who have had a “pass” or “achieved” grade. There is a common field between both datasets that can be used to link them together.
Ultimately, the first dataset will pull out all of the trainees and the second dataset will count how many passes they have been given.

I’m not sure whether the best method would be through an expressions (like above) or through a query. If a query is best, I would not know how to go about doing this. Any help on this would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Below are the two queries that are being used.

Query 1:

```
SELECT
EMP.FULLNAME,
EMP.EMP_ID,
WS_EVENT_STATUS.BRANCH AS "Department",
WS_EVENT_STATUS.STATUS AS "Competency Status"

FROM       
EMP 
INNER JOIN
EMPEVENT ON EMP.EMP_ID = EMPEVENT.EMP_ID

INNER JOIN
WS_PERSONAL_DETAIL ON EMP.EMP_ID = WS_PERSONAL_DETAIL.EMP_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN
WS_EVENT_STATUS ON EMPEVENT.EVENT_SEQ_NO = WS_EVENT_STATUS.EVENT_SEQ_NO

WHERE
(EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID = 'STATUS')
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
EMP.EMP_ID,
EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID,
concat( WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1.ASSDATE, WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2.ASSDATE) AS "Assessment Date",
concat( WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1.STFNAME, WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2.STFNAME) AS "Staff Name",
concat( WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1.GRADE, WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2.GRADE) AS "Grade"

FROM        
EMP 
INNER JOIN
EMPEVENT ON EMP.EMP_ID = EMPEVENT.EMP_ID
INNER JOIN
WS_PERSONAL_DETAIL ON EMP.EMP_ID = WS_PERSONAL_DETAIL.EMP_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1 ON EMPEVENT.EVENT_SEQ_NO = WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1.EVENT_SEQ_NO 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2 ON EMPEVENT.EVENT_SEQ_NO = WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2.EVENT_SEQ_NO 

WHERE
EMP.EMP_ID = EMPEVENT.EMP_ID AND
((EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID = 'TESTFORM1') OR
(EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID = 'TESTFORM2'))
AND                                         
((WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1.ASSDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) OR
(WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2.ASSDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate))
```

Comment: You could use `LookupSet` but it would probably be much simpler to do this at the database end. Can you edit your question, showing the dataset queries.

Comment: Yeah I did try using a 'LookupSet' but it wasn't very successful for me. I will update my post now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this as I don't know what your data tables look like but I think this should work to give you all the data in a single query.

```
SELECT
EMP.FULLNAME,
EMP.EMP_ID,
EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID,
WS_EVENT_STATUS.BRANCH AS "Department",
WS_EVENT_STATUS.STATUS AS "Competency Status",
concat( WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1.ASSDATE, WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2.ASSDATE) AS "Assessment Date",
concat( WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1.STFNAME, WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2.STFNAME) AS "Staff Name",
concat( WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1.GRADE, WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2.GRADE) AS "Grade"

FROM        
EMP 
INNER JOIN
EMPEVENT ON EMP.EMP_ID = EMPEVENT.EMP_ID
INNER JOIN
WS_PERSONAL_DETAIL ON EMP.EMP_ID = WS_PERSONAL_DETAIL.EMP_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1 ON EMPEVENT.EVENT_SEQ_NO = WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1.EVENT_SEQ_NO 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2 ON EMPEVENT.EVENT_SEQ_NO = WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2.EVENT_SEQ_NO 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
WS_EVENT_STATUS ON EMPEVENT.EVENT_SEQ_NO = WS_EVENT_STATUS.EVENT_SEQ_NO

WHERE
EMP.EMP_ID = EMPEVENT.EMP_ID AND
((EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID = 'TESTFORM1') OR
(EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID = 'TESTFORM2'))
AND                                         
((WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1.ASSDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) OR
(WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2.ASSDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate))
AND
(EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID = 'STATUS')
```

There are quite a few things you could do to clean up this query too, but that's a personal thing. Such as...

- Use table aliases to save having to specify the full name name every time you reference a table column ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx )
- There is no need for the first line in hte WHERE clause, you are doing and INNER join between EMP and EMPEVENT on EMP_ID so these will always be the same
- Use IN instead of multiple equals expressions so `AND ((EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID = 'TESTFORM1') OR (EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID = 'TESTFORM2'))` becomes `AND EMPEVENT.EVENT_ID IN('TESTFORM1', 'TESTFORM2')`

**UPDATE:** As the above doesn't work and I can't tell why as I can't see your data, try the following.

```
SELECT a.FullName, a.Emp_ID, a.Department, a.[Competency Status]
        , b.EVENT_ID, b.[Assesment Date], b.[Staff name], b.Grade
        FROM (
              SELECT
                    e.FULLNAME,
                    e.EMP_ID,
                    es.BRANCH AS "Department",
                    es.STATUS AS "Competency Status"
                FROM EMP e
                    INNER JOIN EMPEVENT ee ON e.EMP_ID = ee.EMP_ID
                    INNER JOIN WS_PERSONAL_DETAIL pd ON e.EMP_ID = pd.EMP_ID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN WS_EVENT_STATUS es ON ee.EVENT_SEQ_NO = es.EVENT_SEQ_NO
                  WHERE (ee.EVENT_ID = 'STATUS')
              ) a
          LEFT JOIN
              (
              SELECT
                  e.EMP_ID,
                  ee.EVENT_ID,
                  concat( t1.ASSDATE, t2.ASSDATE) AS "Assessment Date",
                  concat( t1.STFNAME, t2.STFNAME) AS "Staff Name",
                  concat( t1.GRADE, t2.GRADE) AS "Grade"
              FROM EMP e
                  INNER JOIN EMPEVENT ee ON e.EMP_ID = ee.EMP_ID
                  INNER JOIN WS_PERSONAL_DETAIL pd ON e.EMP_ID = pd.EMP_ID 
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN WS_EVENT_TESTFORM1 t1 ON ee.EVENT_SEQ_NO = t1.EVENT_SEQ_NO 
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN WS_EVENT_TESTFORM2 t2 ON ee.EVENT_SEQ_NO = t2.EVENT_SEQ_NO 
              WHERE 
                  ee.EVENT_ID IN ('TESTFORM1', 'TESTFORM2')
                  AND (  
                        (t1.ASSDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) OR
                        (t2.ASSDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
                    )
              ) b
          ON a.EMP_ID = b.EMP_ID
```

The essentially runs both queries then joins them by EMP_ID

Comment: I've tried this version of the query but the sum iif doesn't accurately calculate the value. This is the expression I have used: =SUM(IIF(Fields!Staff.Value ="Trainee" AND Fields!Grade.Value = "Pass" OR Fields!Grade.Value = "Achieved", 1,0))

Comment: Its likely I've overlooked something or your data it not quite what I expected. Can you post a sample of the output from your original queries and the combined query. I might be able to work it out then.

Comment: When the data is run the only difference between the two is that the Department and Competency Status remain blank (no data is returned) in the combined query.

Comment: That would suggest that the where clause is filtering out results. I'll update my answer to provide an alternative solution.

Comment: Great, thank you Alan. I look forward to trying the solution.